# Round off to two decimal places and get positive numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have placed this code in GTM to capture values from the product array and two issues are faced, currently:

```
var aa_ck_items = [];
try{
    var aa_ck_products = analytics_dataLayer.ecommerce.purchase.products || [];

aa_ck_products.forEach(function(element) {
    var currentItem = {
        "unitPrice": Number(element.price) / Number(element.quantity) + Number(element.discount),
        "itemId": element.id,
        "quantity": Number(element.quantity),
        "discount": Number(element.discount),
    }
    aa_ck_items.push(currentItem);
});

}catch(e){}
```

**Issues faced**

1. When the ***unitPrice*** value is sent it has many numbers after the decimal e.g *12.23000002* and I am looking to round it off to two decimal places. I know the two methods we can use Math.round() and .toFixed(). I am not sure how to implement it to the code above.
2. The discount value sometimes comes as a negative number and it always needs to be positive. How do I do that?

Can someone please help? Thank you!

Comment: For **1.** _I am not sure how to implement it to the code above_ <--- simply enclose the computation within `(` & `)` and suffix `.toFixed(2)` (if you need to fix to 2 digits after decimal, for example). Try: `"unitPrice": (Number(element.price) / Number(element.quantity) + Number(element.discount)).toFixed(2),`. For **2.**, _How do I do that?_ <--- `Math.abs()`. Try: `"discount": Math.abs(Number(element.discount)),`

Comment: @jsN00b Perhaps that comment should be an answer?

Answer (score 1):

1. Wrap it all and use .toFixed(2) like you suggested~
2. Do you want to make negative numbers positive, or negative numbers 0?

- If you want to make them positive, you can use Math.abs()
- If you want it to be zero then you can implement a function to do so.

Given your code...

```
aa_ck_products.forEach(function(element) {
    var currentItem = {
        "unitPrice": (Number(element.price) / Number(element.quantity) + Number(element.discount)).toFixed(2),
        "itemId": element.id,
        "quantity": Number(element.quantity),
        "discount": Math.abs(Number(element.discount)),
  // OR "discount": (Number(element.discount) > 0) ? Number(element.discount) : 0,
    }
    aa_ck_items.push(currentItem);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//to approximate a decimal number using fixed-point notation
let number = 123.456;
number.toFixed(2); //expected as: 123.45

//to get the module (positive side) of a number    
let negative_number = -10;
Math.abs(negative_number); //expected as: 10
```

Answer (score 0):

For **1.** *I am not sure how to implement it to the code above* <--- simply enclose the computation within `(` & `)` and suffix `.toFixed(2)` (if you need to fix to 2 digits after decimal, for example).

For **2.** *How do I do that?* <--- Math.abs()

Both the items above are shown (with comments) on below code sample.

```
let aa_ck_items = [];
try {
  const aa_ck_products = analytics_dataLayer.ecommerce.purchase.products || [];
  aa_ck_products.forEach(function(element) {
    const currentItem = {
      "unitPrice": (
        Number(element.price) / Number(element.quantity) + Number(element.discount)
      ).toFixed(2), // <<--- #1 from question, assuming 2 digits after decimal for .toFixed()
      "itemId": element.id,
      "quantity": Number(element.quantity),
      "discount": Math.abs( // <<--- #2 from question, using Math.abs()
        Number(element.discount)
      )
    }
    aa_ck_items.push(currentItem);
  });

} catch (e) {}
```

**NOTE** - The usage of `var` has been modified to `let` or `const` as appropriate.

Below is how I would probably write this code:

```
let aa_ck_items = [];
try {
  const aa_ck_products = analytics_dataLayer.ecommerce.purchase.products || [];
  aa_ck_items = aa_ck_products.map(
    ({price, quantity, discount, id}) => ({
      "unitPrice": (
          Number(price) / Number(quantity) + Number(discount)
        ).toFixed(2),
      "itemId": id,
      "quantity": Number(quantity),
      "discount": Math.abs(Number(discount))
    })
  );
} catch (e) {}
```

Thank you [James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/535480/james) for the suggestion in the comments.